Error with MEAM potential in the hybrid style in LAMMPS
I used the following input file to simulate the interaction between AlN and Cu spheres.
variable x equal 121.2116
variable y equal 121.2116
variable z equal 121.2116
variable t1 equal 300.0
variable t2 equal 1373.0
variable t3 equal 1073.0

units metal
newton on
atom_style atomic
boundary s s s
read_data combination.data
mass 1 26.9815386
mass 2 14.007
mass 3 63.546
neighbor 2 bin
neigh_modify delay 0 every 1

change_box all z delta -50 50 x delta -50 50 y delta -50 50 units box

pair_style hybrid tersoff meam/c eam/fs lj/cut 10
pair_coeff * * tersoff ./AlN.tersoff Al N NULL
pair_coeff * * eam/fs ./Cu1.eam.fs NULL NULL Cu
pair_coeff * * meam/c ./AlCu.meam Al NULL Cu
pair_coeff 2 3 lj/cut 0.056972867226426 2.9399976190467

min_style cg
minimize 0.0001 0.0001 10000 10000

velocity all create ${t1} 898758 mom yes rot yes dist gaussian

thermo 1000
thermo_style custom step temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix 1 all nvt temp ${t2} ${t2} 10 #0.05
dump xyz1 all xyz 1000 dump_1st_nvt.xyz
dump_modify xyz1 element Al N Cu
run 100000
unfix 1
undump xyz1
reset_timestep 0

After I submitted the calculation, LAMMPS gave me the following error message.
LAMMPS (17 Apr 2024)
Reading data file ...
  orthogonal box = (0 -39.763162 -40.5658) to (122.4216 61.448438 60.6458)
  4 by 2 by 4 MPI processor grid
  reading atoms ...
  44511 atoms
  reading velocities ...
  44511 velocities
  read_data CPU = 0.297 seconds
Changing box ...
  orthogonal box = (1.5408348 -37.975695 -88.788333) to (120.6384 59.660971 108.86833)
  orthogonal box = (-48.481075 -37.985458 -88.808099) to (170.66031 59.670735 108.8881)
  orthogonal box = (-48.502989 -88.005224 -88.827868) to (170.68222 109.6905 108.90787)
ERROR: Incorrect args for pair style meam coefficients (../pair_meam.cpp:241)
Last command: pair_coeff * * meam/c ./AlCu.meam Al NULL Cu
srun: error: b08r4n00: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 1
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=16828245.0

Would anyone please tell me how to use the meam potential correctly in the hybrid potential style?
Thank you in advance.

Please proofread this question (and all posts and comments that you post here)!

@Nike Dattani I am sorry for the typo error. I have corrected them. Would you please give me some suggestions on my problem? Thank you.

You had more proofreading to do, so I made another edit just now. As for your request for me to give you suggestions for your problem, hopefully Andrey's answer is sufficient for you. Aside from CW answers, I have only answered one question with the LAMMPS tag on this site, and my answer had nothing to do with LAMMPS. Please refrain from sending direct requests for people to answer your question just because they have commented on your question (especially within a few hours of asking). We have 8000+ members to answer your question :).

@Nike Dattani Thank you for the correction. I will be more precise about my request next time.

I'm going to guess you need to specify both the overall MEAM library file as it is provided with LAMMPS, followed by the specific parameter file for your elements. Example given in the (current as of this writing) LAMMPS documentation for pair_style meam:

pair_coeff * * library.meam Si C sic.meam Si Si Si C

For your system, I suspect only the atom identities, species ordering for the second file, and the paths to libraries would need to be updated.
Depending on your LAMMPS build, you will also need to switch between meam and meam/c since at some point between 2020 and now the C++ that is signified by the /c has become the default in LAMMPS and the /c was dropped.
Let us know how it goes!

Thank you for your suggestion. After I corrected my potential setting as follows, the error was gone. '''pair_style hybrid tersoff meam eam/fs lj/cut 10
pair_coeff * * tersoff ./AlN.tersoff Al N NULL
pair_coeff * * meam ./library.AlCu.meam Al Cu ./AlCu.meam Al NULL Cu
pair_coeff 2 3 lj/cut 0.056972867226426 2.9399976190467
pair_coeff * * eam/fs ./Cu1.eam.fs NULL NULL Cu'''

I am trying to write these potential settings into another dialogue but I do not know how to do that. sorry for the messy text.
